# bug report on <pre> is bigger than its frame

Tags: bug, status-declined

If you view the following picture, you can see when I try to flag there is a bug:

[image: screenshot-of-flagging]

I use:
`firefox 31.6.0`
`Debian 9 (Stretch)`

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm using Debian 9 (Stretch)

Comment: There seems to be another report of this same problem, so this is likely not a problem on your side. However, Deb 9 only entered development a week ago, so do consider that some issues could be your end. Even if you are using "testing" and not "sid" I doubt it'll be without issues yet :)

Comment: This only happens on FF on certain *nix distros. We will not be fixing it as it is cosmetic only.